# I am trying to set attributes on HTML elements that are being built within an *ngFor loop, but document.getElementsByTagName("textarea") does not work

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, attributes

I am working in the Ionic framework with Angular. I have a block of html code that creates an ion-textarea element in an *ngFor loop.
I have found that using document.getElementsByTagName("textarea") does not work on any html elements within *ngFor or *ngIf blocks (the collection it returns is empty). It seems like this is a known Angular issue, but does anyone know a workaround? I want to globally set attributes on the textareas in my app. It works for html elements not within angular directives (i.e. ngFor and ngIf).
Is there a good place in the typescript code to call document.getElementsByTagName("textarea") that would return a collection of the elements and not just an empty collection?

Comment: You don't use getelements Dom manipulation in angular application (only if you really need it and know what you are doing) . Use the angular away of adding classes to elements.n

Comment: it feels like the document query is performed before the ngFor finishes rendering. That might be the reason for your call not to find it.  Do you mind sharing some code? without it it is hard to advise you on what to do.

Comment: @cloned is right you should use the angular way of getting things. I used this approach recently for working with a canvas element: set a name with hash: #textAreaName on your html element, then you can  reference with viewChild like so:   @ViewChild('textAreaName')
  textArea: ElementRef<HTMLElement>; The *ngFor* may be tricky if you can't set those identifiers ahead of time